# PHP MySQL - Join tables with same content?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Ok so I know we can join tables 'across' in MySQL to tables using a id column.

I have two databases where I need to join two tables that are almost identical.

I need to join these 'down', e.g similar to inserting the whole of one table into the other. Not a normal cross join.

Does MySQL allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` is a good way to accomplish this.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Just make sure number of columns being returned are the same, and data type matches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `UNION` - the only condition is to select the same amount of columns from both select quesries (both tables):

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table1

UNION

SELECT d, e, f, g FROM table2
```

Common issue is to order the results from `UNION`, so here is solution:

```
SELECT a AS order_by, b, c, d FROM table1
UNION
SELECT d, e, f AS order_by, g FROM table2
ORDER BY order_by DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 
    SELECT * FROM database2.table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, just use full database name before table, make sure your user have permissions on both databases.

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM database1.table t1
 JOIN database2.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

Comment: are you talking about sql join or table content join?